# Fulton Harris Representation theory exercise 3.10

Tags: representation-theory

This exercise asks you to build the character table of $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}/3)$. I have found numerous resources that solve the problem in sophisticated ways, and for more general $F_p$ field.

However, given that this problem is posed in chapter 3 of Fulton & Harris, I was wondering whether there is a simple way to solve it with the methods covered so far.

Comment: Have you calculated the derived subgroup?

Comment: Sorry, I'm only a physicist. But again, the derived subgroup also sounds more sophisticated than what you'd expect in chapter 3 of Fulton & Harris. They haven't even introduced induced representations at that point in the book. Clearly there must be a simpler way.

Comment: I'd also like to see some ideas for how to do this. I figured out all the 1 dimensional and the 3 dimensional representation, and a little staring will convince you the 3 remaining representations are all dimension 2. But how to get them?